# How to delete personal projects from wakatime?

Tags: wakatime

I keep my working hours on wakatime. It's really great web-site for developers.
I want to ask you, how can I delete personal projects from wakatime?
I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 5):

To delete a project, you must first remove it's coding activity using the [Coding Activity Delete Tool](https://wakatime.com/code-delete-tool).

After removing the project's coding activity, you can delete the project from the project's dashboard. A project dashboard without coding activity will have a "trash icon" in the top right corner to delete that project.

To exclude projects from being logged in the future, add the project's path to your `$HOME/.wakatime.cfg` file under the [exclude setting](https://github.com/wakatime/wakatime#configuring). The exclude setting takes a list of regexes, which if matching a file or project's path will exclude that file/project from your dashboard.

The [WakaTime FAQ](https://wakatime.com/faq#create-projects) has more info about how projects are automatically detected, renamed, and excluded.

Comment: I've created the tag [tag:wakatime] as its the only one that seemed useful for this question. FYI.